# Undo/Redo implementation for a CRUD AngularJS app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, undo, undo-redo

We are considering building a Excel-like app in AngularJS where we would like undo/redo support for the cell editing.

Any advice on the best strategy to implement this?

I am not just thinking of undoing text just entered in a textbox. I mean entering data in several cells and then undoing each of those entries.

I have experimented with pushing the current model on a stack before each modification. That makes it possible to undo by restoring the model to a previous state. However, how do I combine this with REST CRUD interaction?

The "natural" way of resolving the CRUD is to do an immediate REST call to the backend  (updating the database) for each modification. But then undoing will just modify model in Angular, not the database. And there is no simple way of posting the delta between the two models over REST.

Comment: If cells are just input fields then CTRL+Z and CTRL+SHIFT+Z will do undo redo on those.

Comment: @jcubic I have clarified my question as regards to this.

Comment: I have removed any reference to ember from the question so that it should be completely on-topic.

Comment: hi Klas, try reading about the command processor pattern. In general for command processor, you (the controller in the case of angularJS) would create a command (write on excel) and send to a command processor which would store the command and execute it. In the case of undo, you can ask the command processor to undo the action.

Comment: I cover AngularJS Memento Factories here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45435927/1122851

Answer (score 1):

I would argue this is functionality not particular to angular-js but rather something achieved with the capture of state.

Your actions (such as editing, adding, moving cells, etc) would all alter the state of your app, the deltas of theses states could be pushed onto a structure that can be rolled back through.

If you undo, say 2 actions, then start a fresh action, then the 2 most states would be removed and the new states pushed on.

Applications such as Photoshop store history similar to this (and for similar reasons don't permit unlimited undo).

Again though, I would argue that this is functionality that should not be bound to the angular framework, but you could obviously serve it up as an angular service.

Comment: Ok, but I thought that this would be something that could be integrated with the databinding perhaps.
I am new to angular so it is unfortunately not obvious how it would be served up as an angular service.